# How to define a function that creates for loops embeded in each other with python?

Tags: python, function, loops

I am programming using python3. I was looking for a program that could generate every combinations of 16 chords (for music composing) choosing between a C chord or a G chord. I succeeded by using this code:

```
chords = ['C', 'G']
progressions = []

 for chord1 in chords:
     for chord2 in chords:
         for chord3 in chords:
             for chord4 in chords:
                 for chord5 in chords:
                     for chord6 in chords:
                         for chord7 in chords:
                             for chord8 in chords:
                                 for chord9 in chords:
                                     for chord10 in chords:
                                         for chord11 in chords:
                                             for chord12 in chords:
                                                 for chord13 in chords:
                                                     for chord14 in chords:
                                                         for chord15 in chords:
                                                                  for chord16 in chords:

                                                                       progressions.append([chord1, chord2, chord3, chord4,
                                                                                 chord5, chord6, chord7, chord8,
                                                                                 chord9, chord10, chord11, chord12,
                                                                                 chord13, chord14, chord15, chord16]
                                                                                )
 print(progressions)
 print(f'{len(progressions)} progressions generated.')
```

Here is what I get as an output (It's the exact output that I need):
[ ... ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G'], ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'C'], ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'G'], ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'C'], ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G'], ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'C'], ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G'], ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C'], ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G']]
65536 progressions generated.

Obviously, this code is not as short and cute as it could be. That's why I would like to define a function that generates loops. To make it even better, I thought it would be the best to add as a parameter for the function the number of loop it is supposed to create so it would be chosen every time the program would be executed.

Thank you in advance

Luc

Comment: See the `itertools` module.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I recommend you use recursion for solving this problem

Comment: Recursion might be more elegant but it would be just as slow as creating the for loops. He should use itertools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of your `chords` set/list with itself 16 times. For that, you have [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in Python.

For example, to achieve the same effect of your code, you would do something like this:

```
import itertools

chords = ['C', 'G']
progressions = list(itertools.product(chords, repeat=16))

print(progressions)
print(f'{len(progressions)} progressions generated.')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for. I even tried your example with different parameters. I tried with chords = ['C', 'G', 'Am'] and repeat=15 and I obtained: [ ... ('Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'G'), ('Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am', 'Am')]
14348907 progressions generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the permutations function from the itertools module to accomplish this.

E.g.

```
import itertools

chords = ['A', 'B']
depth = 16

progressions = itertools.permutations(chords * depth)

print(f'{len(list(progressions))} progressions generated.')
```

Comment: I tried to use your code, but it doesn't work in my PyCharm. I got this: TypeError: object of type 'itertools.permutations' has no len(). I am not familiar with itertools, so I don't know if it's supposed to give a list or a tuple as an output, but I sure am going to look at this package. Thank you.

Comment: Nice catch, I've updated the code so it works. The itertools result would need to be converted to a list in order to use len on it.